# Chrome apps that run on startup?

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-application, startup

What would be the easiest way for me to set up a Chrome extension that starts when I log in to my Windows account, and can be connected to a WebSocket server to check for, say, new messages, and then pop open a desktop notification, that clicks to the messages web page?

I expect that making an extension is straight forward, as well as getting it to communicate with WebSockets, and making the desktop notification.

But what about making it automatically start when I log in to the computer? What would be a good way to do this in Windows? I am not interested in having the chrome browser to open up at log in, but I certainly don't mind if I see Chrome in the task bar.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into chrome.runtime.onStartUp: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onStartup, which is 
"Fired when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up."

Also, you can use chrome.alarms to schedule a function to run every minute or so, to open a WebSocket somewhere, etc.

The app may try to unload itself if there are no active windows, so you can call some action in chrome.runtime.onSuspend (like loading an XHR somewhere) to cause onSuspendCanceled to trigger.